# Windows 11 why is traffic bound to one interface is sent to another

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, routing

On a Windows 11 machine I have my regular wifi interface (192.168.3.7) and a Wintun Tunnel interface (configured to have IP 192.168.3.6). The routing tables are set up so that all traffic should go to the Wintun Tunnel by default. However I'd like to make some connections use the wifi interface. I tried creating a socket and binding it to that interface's IP, but the traffic is still routed to Wintun. Are there other settings somewhere that affect routing decisions? Note that this setup works as expected on another Windows 11 machine, so I think it may be due to some unusual setting on the affected machine.

Example Python code for how I create the socket and bind it to the wifi interface:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("192.168.3.7",0))
sock.connect(("www.google.com",80)) // these TCP packets still get sent to the Wintun Tunnel
```

Routing info:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 11...........................Wintun Tunnel
  9...ce 47 40 77 44 bc ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
  2...ee 47 40 77 44 bc ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
  8...cc 47 40 77 44 bc ......Realtek RTL8852BE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe Adapter
 18...cc 47 40 77 44 bd ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.3.1   192.168.3.7     30
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.3.6      6
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
     192.168.3.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.3.7    286
     192.168.3.0    255.255.255.0         On-link    192.168.3.6    261
   192.168.3.6  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.3.6    261
   192.168.3.7  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.3.7    286
   192.168.3.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.3.7    286
   192.168.3.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.3.6    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.3.7    286
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.3.6    261
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.3.7    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.3.6    261
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: You have two `0.0.0.0` routes, meaning two default routes. The one to gateway `192.168.3.6` has the metric `6`, while the one to gateway `192.168.3.7` has the metric `30`. As the lower metric has the priority, gateway `192.168.3.6` is the referred route. The question is rather how does it work correctly on the other computer.

Comment: I thought you could use bind to force a socket to use a specific network interface? See for example the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615677/how-to-force-traffic-on-specific-network-adapter

Comment: The answer in that post uses binding to an IP address, not to a physical interface. To bind to a specific interface needs other API, but programming questions belong on Stack Overflow. The best I can offer here is to modify your routes so as to have only one default address.